# Issue on Assigining CSS to Generated Classes from Loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to generate 5 div but with different class number like ball1, ball2 ... and ball5 by following code which works for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
         var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
         $('.bar').append("<div class='ball"+i+"'></div>");
    }
});
```

Now I would like to assign different CSS style for the number in following CSS from rand number above

```
-webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite linear;
```

Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Are you asking how you'd add a style for a class? I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: Where should be this random number used? Animation time?

Comment: I would like to use the rand instead of 1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use inline styles for each `div`. I would also recommend setting only `animation-duration` property, while other parts of the `animation` prop can be defined in the CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
        $('.bar').append($("<div />", {
            attr: {
                class: 'ball'+i
            },
            css: {
                webkitAnimationDuration: rand + 's',
                mozAnimationDuration: rand + 's'
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.bar > div {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite linear;
}
```

By the way, your loop creates 4 divs, not 5.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dK5N3/

Comment: @Behseini I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: I already tried this inline style $('.bar').append("<div class='ball"+i+"'style='-webkit-animation: bounce "+ rand+"s infinite linear;-moz-animation: bounce " +rand+"s infinite linear;'></div>");

Comment: but it just create two divs

Comment: I added a working example at the bottom of my answer. If it doesn't work for you, there must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Here is mine, can you please chek why not working on my example http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5w9Gn/

Comment: Few things: I didn't know you needed the `ball..` classes for some other purposees. I added it now. Then, you added `animation` styles for the `.bar` div, not for its children. And finally, you only see two balls because you only defined styles for `.ball1` and `.ball2`. Other 3 are there but you can't see them - they have no styles (like width, height and background). Here's your corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/5w9Gn/1/